# Custom receiver doesn't call onLoad after disconnect / reconnect

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

When I disconnect and reconnect without​shutting down the receiver from my Android app, the cast receiver doesn't receive onLoad events anymore.
A custom messagebus still works.

`mRemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus` with timeout set to 15 seconds, times out.

I can see that the cast receiver receives a message:

```
[cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"requestId\":2,\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":  ... }}
```

CastPlayer.prototype.load is never called.

MediaManager message received is never show.

I'm not sure where to look for the error.

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue with the Google Cast sample apps? Are there any error messages in the Chrome Remote Debugger?

If you have a reliable way to reproduce the issue, then file a bug with a sample stream: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: The error was in my receiver, I'll add an answer for this, describing it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred only after casting a picture, because I handle this on my own.

After `self.resetMediaElement_()` I missed for mimeType image/*:

```
this.mediaElement_.addEventListener('stalled', this.onBuffering_.bind(this), false);
this.mediaElement_.addEventListener('waiting', this.onBuffering_.bind(this), false);
this.onLoadOrig_(new cast.receiver.MediaManager.Event(cast.receiver.MediaManager.EventType.LOAD, (info.message), info.senderId));
```